# How can I enable default value display under Django CharField

Tags: python, html, css, django

I have in Django *models.py* this line:

```
class Method1(models.Model):
    # other param
    species_param   = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=(('mouse', 'Mouse'), ('human','Human'))
```

It looks like this:

[image]

Note that the default value is set to `----`.
I want to set it to `Mouse`. How can I do it?

I'd like also to remove the `---` altogether.

Comment: Are you using a standard `ModelForm` to render the form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not test it but it may solve your problem:

```
class Mehod1(models.Model):
    # other param
    species_param = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=(('mouse', 'Mouse'), ('human', 'Human')), default='mouse')
```

Answer (score 0):

**Suggestion :**

Try with `initial='mouse'`

**Documentation :** https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#initial

Comment: I tried this: ` species_param   =models.CharField(max_length=20,initial='mouse', choices=(('mouse', 'Mouse'), ('human','Human'))`. But failed during migration. I get `TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'initial'.`